# Object doesn't support property or method 'valid'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

My code is throwing the following error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'valid'.

This is because the current form has no validation. That is OK. All I want is to check in advance whether or not I can apply the method `valid` to the current form to avoid the annoying JavaScript error.

That is all I want. E.g. `if(form.isValidatable()) form.valid()`

There is nothing wrong with the code. All I need is to know whether or not calling a method or property is going to throw an exception.

```js
form.submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid())
      onFormIsValid($(this));
    else
      onFormIsInvalid($(this));
  });
```

UPDATE: I am new to jquery and thank you for your help!!!!! What I am trying to do is to disable all the inputs just before submit and after validation. I do not manage to get the submitHandler being called and it is really hard to realize why. That is why I am doing this solution. See my code. How can I improve this?

I want to apply it to all forms in my solution....

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var form = $("form");

  form.bind('invalid-form.validate', function() {
    onFormIsInvalid($(this));
  });

  form.submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid())
      onFormIsValid($(this));
    else
      onFormIsInvalid($(this));
  });
});

function onFormIsValid(form) {
  $("input", form).prop("readonly", "readonly");
  $("input[type=submit]", form).prop("disabled", true);

  $("input[type=submit]", form).each(function () {
    $(this).data("val", $(this).val());
  });

  $("input[type=submit]", form).val("Processing...");
}

function onFormIsInvalid(form) {
  $("input", form).prop("readonly", null);
  $("input[type=submit]", form).prop("disabled", false);

  $("input[type=submit]", form).each(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).data("val"));
  });
}
```

If on the other hand I do the following the submit handler does not get called at all. No error, no clue, nothing. I place a break point and it is like the handler is not there.

```js
form.validate({
  submitHandler: function () {
   onFormIsValid($(this));
  }
 });

  form.bind('invalid-form.validate', function() {
    onFormIsInvalid($(this));
  });
```

Comment: `if (!$.validator) { return; }`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, `if (!$.validator)` will only tell you that the plugin is loaded, right?  I think the OP wants to know if one particular form has been initialized for validation with `.validate()`.

Comment: @Sparky, That's the reason for the `?` :)  - not sure I understand what OP wants

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes, what he's asking seems like a very roundabout way for doing something.

Comment: Quote OP:  *"What I am trying to do is to disable all the inputs just before submit and after validation."* ~ use the `submitHandler`!

Comment: I know but somehow it does not get called. However, invalid-form.validate does work. I am lost here.

Comment: Are you using Unobtrusive Validation with your ASP?  If so, look at this:  http://jsfiddle.net/9obe1b35/  - if NOT, then look at this:  http://jsfiddle.net/9obe1b35/1/

Comment: I tried again and nop... Not getting called. Is there like an strategy to realize why some handler does not get called? This is making me crazy.

Comment: The error message you posted in your update seems to indicate that you have **not included the jQuery Validate plugin**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
form.submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid())
      onFormIsValid($(this));
    else
      onFormIsInvalid($(this));
});
```

This seems like a very roundabout way and is the wrong approach.  The plugin automatically captures the click and blocks the submit, so your custom `submit()` handler will likely conflict.

You could be using the built-in `submitHandler` and `invalidHandler` callback functions... then you would not need to worry about how to call `.valid()`, since `submitHandler` only fires when valid and `invalidHandler` only fires when invalid.

Demo 1: http://jsfiddle.net/9obe1b35/1/

If you're using the Unobtrusive Validation helper plugin built into ASP, then the `.validate()` method is constructed automatically and you cannot put these callback functions inside.  Instead, you can put your custom `submitHandler` and `invalidHandler` functions into [the `jQuery.validator.setDefaults()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/).

Demo 2 (Unobtrusive): http://jsfiddle.net/9obe1b35/2/