# I'm trying to highlight my inputs with jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm working in mvc. 
This is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreatePost", "Posts", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "save-post-form" }))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5" id="post-details-div">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Post Title</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "off" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Post Description</label>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "off" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Post Cover Picture</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostCoverFile, new { @type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PostCoverFile, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="post-content-div">
        <label>Content</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Content, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@section scripts{

<script>
    require(["createPost"], function (module) {
        $("#navbar-links").find("li[data-name='posts']").addClass('active');
        module.load();

    });
</script>
}
```

And this is my js file. I have only the form validation.
 I'm using require js:

```
define(["jquery", "mainModule", "ckeditor", "jqueryValidateUnobtrusive", "bootstrapTagsInput", "typeAhead"], function ($, module, CKEDITOR) {
    var bind = function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {

        console.log("ready");
        $('#save-post-form').validate({
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).addClass('error');
                $(element).removeClass('valid');
                console.log("ceva");
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).removeClass('error');
                $(element).addClass('valid');
                console.log("ceva");
            }
        });
    });
var createPostPage = {
    load: function () {
        bind();
    }
}

return createPostPage;
});
```

Nothing happens and I don't know what is wrong...
Please help me. The validation works, but the highlight won't trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The validation works, but the highlight won't trigger.

That's because you're already using the unobtrusive-validation plugin as part of ASP.  As such, Unobtrusive Validation automatically constructs and calls the `.validate()` method.  This means that your instance of `.validate()` is always ignored.  *(As per jQuery Validate's design, the `.validate()` method can only be called **once** as the plugin's initialization on your form, and any subsequent calls are always ignored.)*.

In other words, once you call `.validate()` (initializes the plugin) on the form, the options are locked in and cannot be changed dynamically by calling `.validate()` again.

You have two options to over-ride the default `highlight` and `unhighlight`...

1. Remove the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin from your project and construct `.validate()` method as you desire.  Gives you full control but FWIW, you will not get the "unobtrusive" features and benefits of the Unobtrusive Validation plugin.
2. Put your `highlight` and `unhighlight` options within [the `.setDefaults()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/) instead, and then be sure this method goes someplace ***before*** Unobtrusive calls `.validate()`.  To achieve this, you'll probably have to make sure `.setDefaults()` is not inside of any DOM ready event handler.  Just remember that anything you put inside of `.setDefaults()` will affect **all** forms on the page.

Read more here:  [stackoverflow.com/a/40899630/594235](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40899630/594235)

and here (see edit #2 and comments section):  [stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235)

Comment: @AndreiB, you're welcome.  Please "accept" this answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: @AndreiB, click the check mark in the upper left side next to my answer.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below overridden CSS worked for me. Thought it would be helpful for those who need a quick fix,

```
.field-validation-error {
    color: #ff0000;
}


.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.valid {

}
```